# What's the best way to watch the change of data in Cocoa

Tags: swift, cocoa

I have a singleton to store some global data for my macOS app, one of my ViewController keeps modifying data. I want to simultaneously show the changes in a View, which is related to another ViewController. what 's the best way to do this?

**Global Data:**

```
final class AppData {

    static var logs: [LogData] = []
}
```

**ViewController 1:**

```
class FirstViewController: NSViewController {

   AppData.logs.append(newLogData)
}
```

**ViewController 2:**

```
class SecondViewController: NSViewController {

   // what's the best way to simultaneously watch the change of AppData.logs? 
}
```

Comment: There could be many ways to achieve this. If you have this requirement for only once or twice then simply use `delegate` with `protocol`.

Comment: I probably will have this requirement in many places. I'm very new to Cocoa, I don't know what are the common ways to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your App is planned to be macOS only you can use a [NSObjectController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsobjectcontroller). This is definitively the easiest approach and you can do most of the configuration in Interface builder. It works internally with bindings. In case of an array you want to observe, you would use a NSArrayController.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the notificationcenter

In viewcontroller2 add:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    notificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
        selector: #selector(view1DidChange),
        name: "view1DidChange",
        object: nil
    )
}

@objc private func view1DidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
     // Do something
}
```

In viewcontroller1 add

```
        notificationCenter.default.post(name: "view1DidChange", object: self)
```

This can be repeated in every class, that should listen.

Answer (score 0):

Here i am sharing the Delegate & Protocol approach to achieve this functionality.

```
final class AppData {

    static var logs: [LogData] = []
}

    protocol FirstViewControllerDelegate {
        func ViewControllerDelegate(appData:[LogData])
    }

    class FirstViewController: NSViewController {
        var delegate:FirstViewControllerDelegate?

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            AppData.logs.append(newLogData)
            self. delegate?.ViewControllerDelegate(appData: AppData.logs)

        }
    }

    class SecondViewController: NSViewController,FirstViewControllerDelegate {
        var firstViewController:FirstViewController = FirstViewController()
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            self.firstViewController.delegate = self
        }
        func ViewControllerDelegate(appData:[LogData]){
            //Do Update the UI
        }
    }
```